# How to convert Ruby code using Selenium into Selenese script?

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium

How can I convert Ruby code using Selenium commands into Selenese script?

For example, how could I get the Selenese version of the following Ruby code?

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox # firefox,ie,chrome
@driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"

ele =@driver.find_element(:name,'q')
ele.send_keys "Technologies"
ele.submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Selenium IDE, the Firefox plugin ? you can convert Selenium test into an other language script : Ruby, test jUnit, TestNG !

But i am not sure you can do Ruby to Selenium.

Comment: No, am using ruby shell(irb) to execute commands. In irb, i need to generate selenese script.